# Premier Pro producing a 4 hour video that's corrupted

Tags: premiere

I have a project in Premier Pro that is basically just stitching together a series of videos from a helmet camera into one video that is 4 hours 30 long. In Premier pro all looks good and I can watch the video in the preview window no problem at all.

The exported video is different though. It is fine up to about 3:26 but then it doesn't play. In windows media player I get an error if I try to move the play head past this point. The video was uploaded to youTube here:

and you can see that it just removed the end of the video.

Is there some sort of limit on H.264 video length? I highly doubt that!

What can I do to start debugging what is going on here?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The first place I would look would be in the encoder log files. If you used Adobe Media Encoder you will find the log files here:

#### Windows 7 & 8:

```
C:\Users\[user]\Documents\Adobe\Adobe Media Encoder\8.0\AMEEncodingLog.txt
```

#### Mac OS:

```
/Users/[user]/Documents/Adobe/Adobe Media Encoder/8.0/AMEEncodingLog.txt
```

To view the log file, choose File > Show Log or press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>.

**There are two log files:**

1. AMEEncodingLog.txt - *for successfully encoded jobs*
2. AMEEncodingErrorLog.txt - *for jobs that failed, or were stopped by the user*

See the help: https://helpx.adobe.com/media-encoder/using/log-files.html

**Check the last entry in each log file and see if your video was encoded correctly.**

- If the log file points to an encoding error, investigate that
- If the log file indicates no error then attempt to play the video in a different media player and see if the problem still persists

I use VLC media player because I've found it to be most reliable.  There is also a debugging console in VLC that can be useful.